# On multibit how do I update my sending address?

Tags: wallet, address, multibit

I have bitcoin in my transactions but it does not appear in my wallet.
It says updates stopped

Answer (score 2):

You can get the 'updates stopped' if MultiBit detects some other user or process has edited one of the MultiBit files.

If you close down MultiBit and restart it it reloads all files.

There is more help on if transactions don't appear in your wallet in the multibit.org help so also have a look through there.